# Auto layout sticking to wrong side

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I have a checkbox that is sticking to the left side of the view. I want it to stick next to the controls to it's right or the same distance from the right side of the view. How do I do that in Xcode (IB)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Editor -> Pin -> Trailing Space to Superview

Then I can delete the bad "Leading Space to Superview"